# SharePoint List Autoincrement number field?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, calculated-column

I need a autoincrement number using number field ( I set default value is 5000 once add the items it will increase one by one) in SharePoint. Can anyone help me using formula.

Answer (score 0):

You can use calculated columns, generally set to =(your column)+1

For example:

[image]

Generally we can also complete this requirement through flow/SharePoint Designer Workflow

https://www.enjoysharepoint.com/create-auto-increment-column-in-sharepoint-list/

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/auto-increment-number-field-in-a-sharepoint-list/m-p/1141477